# UISegmentedControl behaves in a weird way on UITableView Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableviewsectionheader

I created a Custom Cell to replace `UITableViewSectionHeader` with a protocol to process when `UISegmentedControl.index` is changed so i can order the table by name or value:

[image: Custom Cell]

```
import UIKit
protocol OrdenarTableViewDelegate {
func ordenarTableView(cell: OrdenarTableViewCell)
}
class OrdenarTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var delegate: OrdenarTableViewDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedOrdenar: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func alteraOrdenacao(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    delegate?.ordenarTableView(self)
}
```

On the UITableViewControler I referenced the protocol

```
class SelecionadasTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, OrdenarTableViewDelegate {
```

and implemented it:

```
    // MARK: - Ordenar Delegate
func ordenarTableView(cell: OrdenarTableViewCell) {
    if cell.segmentedOrdenar.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        listaCervejas = bancoDeDados.selecionaCervejas(false)
    } else {
        listaCervejas = bancoDeDados.selecionaCervejas(true)
    }
    ordenarCervejas = cell.segmentedOrdenar.selectedSegmentIndex
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When I select the index 1, the app works just fine, but when index 0 is selected the action is only performed if click on a `UITextField` on any other cell or I pull the table down for refreshing (which by the way is not implemented to refresh)

Is there anything that I'm missing? Because it just feels really awkward.

---

### *I notice that the problem only occurs when I click one option and then the other on the `UISegmentedControl` without touching nowhere else on the screen...*

Comment: Please add all your Tableview datasource code.

Comment: I'd advise you to use a UIViewController instead, add a view that would have your segmented controls above the tableview. Ensure to set the delegate and datasource to the controller and that the controller conforms to tableview datasource and delegate. Less headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution. You can drag the IBAction to the tableViewController instead. Then it works just fine!!
Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you reload the tableview, everything added to the table view will be reloaded. Check the selected segment index every time and reset this after table reloading.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but the Selected index only changes when you pull the tableview and not when you click on the segmented control...

Answer (score 1):

U can created a Custom View to replace tableHeaderView, try it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the update of the cell is not executed. Is the reloadTable executed on the mainThread?

Include a print log statement in CellForRowAtIndexPath to find out.